# What's the best way to learn android for someone with no previous programming experience?

Tags: android

I really want to get into android programming and I've already read two books and a lot of the stuff that is going on here. Thanks a lot. This site has already become my very favorite resource. Anyhow, does somebody have any additional tips on how to accelerate the time to take off? Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I learn Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949818/how-can-i-learn-android)

Comment: Thank you very much for these leads. I saw some (not all) of these questions but thought my situation was a little different since I really have zero previous experience or programming knowledge. But maybe you are right. Excuse me, please :/

Comment: Ouch. Already one vote down. :( Not a great start I guess. Thanks for the very nice answers though. I guess I will consider the question of how to get into Java first then.

Comment: See this for learning java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356137/how-to-learn-java-from-scratch  In the future, if you know that your question has already been partially answered, include that information in your question with a link to that question, and point out what exactly makes your question different.

Comment: To get started with android quickly just visit http://www.developandroidapp.com/?p=21 link

Comment: Maybe try some cool website like teamtreehouse.com or follow vogella tutorials.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's like wanting to jump straight into a Formula 1 car and race in a Grand Prix before you've ever had even a single lesson driving a regular car. First tackle some basic non-Android programming. It's "just Java", and there's lots you can do with Java without having to deal with the Android platform on top of everything else.

Especially if you've never programmed before. Get the core programming concepts clear in your head first, then work your way up to a specific platform.

Answer (score 2):

I started out reading a couple of books, but didnt feel I got into programming fast enough. So I just dove into it and started making a simple app and then googled (and used stack overflow) ALOT when I needed help..

I suggest following the tutorials and guides on http://developer.android.com and just jump into it

Comment: +1 on this. With writing software, you can't learn much of anything without doing.

Answer (score 0):

Learn java and start with the [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)
They are really good :)

You can do both (java and tutorials) semi at the same time, althoug some basis in java is a good thing :)

Answer (score 0):

I find that books are a real help, I recently bought an android application for dummies book, which is helpful for revising the basics. It would deem that you are already well on your way - after all, you are using a website like stack overflow!

Personally, I would recommend looking at C# before or at the same time as Java, they both have a similar syntax and both have very good IDE's. If you're looking at the web as a potential outlet for your skills, then PHP is a sort of similar option.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you play with App Inventor for a while also. This will let you dive in and start learning about what goes into an android application without the daunting task of staring and neverending lines of code.

http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to learn programming. I started by reading "Learn C++ in 21 days" but Android is Java-based so you would probably want to start with that (although C/C++ is still my recommendation for someone just starting out). However, be careful - the current Java books out there focus a lot on Swing and teach using NetBeans. Swing is useless if you are only interested in Android and most development is done in Eclipse, not NetBeans.

Now that I think of it, you only need to know very basic programming to start with Android (classes, functions, variables, types, inheritance, loops and maybe some simple algorithms) and the rest you can learn from an Android book. Here are some recommendations: [The Best Books for Developing on the Android Platform](http://log.siineiolekala.net/lang/en/2011/02/learning-android-the-best-books-for-developing-on-the-android-platform/). There are good resources online as well but it is mostly pure documentation and only a couple low-level tutorials.

In general, you should be prepared that if you want to learn how to program, it will take time.